# Is is possible to instantiate the parent of an abstract class in the child of the abstract class in PHP?

Tags: php, abstract-class, superclass

Hopefully the title made sense and hopefully my question does as well.

So I need to instantiate a Sql class at the start of every page on my site so all other classes can have a valid mysql resource to do queries, updates, etc. without creating multiple Sql objects.
However, currently my classes extend an abstract class for different implementations of functions based on the class context.

**Question:** In a child of the abstract class, could I use `parent::_construct` to bypass the abstract superclass and instantiate the Sql class from which the abstract extends?

**EX.**

```
class Sql {
    function _construct() {
        //get valid db resource
    }

    function query() {
        //// query code
    }
}

abstract class Display extends Sql {
    function show() {
       return $this->displayRecipe();
    }        

    abstract function getRecipe();
}


class Members extends Display {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function getRecipe($member_id) {
        return $this->query("select * from recipes where member=$member_id");
    }
}
```

As you can see I neet to use the `function query()` of the Sql class which is a granparent class now. However, with the abstract class in the middle, would this throw an exception and break?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work:

```
Class Person{
    public $age;
    public $name;
    public $school;
    public function __construct($age,$name,$school){
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->school = $school;
        echo "It works!";
    }
}


abstract class Student extends Person{
}

class UniversityStudent extends Student{

    public function __construct($age,$name,$shcool){
        parent::__construct($age,$name,$school);
    }
}

$x = new UniversityStudent(20,"Paul","ULA");

echo $x->age;
```

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation guys!!

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted should work just fine because the constructor in class Members will run the constructor of the parent `parent::__construct()`, which will run the constructor in `Sql` because __construct is not being overloaded in class Display.

I hope I explained that well enough, but give it a try :)
Just make sure your construct method has 2 underscores in the Sql class; it only has 1 in the code you posted.